# Sharepoint 2010 server farm

Tags: active-directory, sql-server, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Here is my current Sharepoint 2010 setup. I have 3 VM's running on the same server. The 3 VM's are as follows (all Windows 2008 R2)

1) Active Directory server 
2) Sharepoint server 
3) SQL Server

The initial setup was done by another IT staff who has now left the company. The problem I have is that I have co-workers in another country (Asia), and they are experiencing extremely slow setup because they have to VPN in to access Sharepoint.

**How can I expand the Sharepoint 2010 server farm?** Here are several scenarios I can think of:

1) Setup another Sharepoint server VM on the local server in Asia, and have it point to the same SQL server 
2) Setup another SQL server on the local server in Asia, but the problem is how do I sync the databases?

Ideally I would want employees in the US and Asia access the same Sharepoint with the same information, with an acceptable speed (ie: loading a page that takes up to 20 secs is a little ridiculous..)

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The recommended solutions hear would be:

1. Install a new SharePoint server in Asia and have it point to your local SQL Server.
2. Expose the existing SharePoint server to the Internet and have the users in Asia connect via the Internet instead of VPN.

Option 1 will give them a fast connection between the user and the web server, but the connections to the database server will be slow.

Option 2 will give them a slow connection to the web server but the connection to the database server will be fast.

You'll probably have to test both configurations to see which option works better.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I wasn't sure if option #1 would work, is there any specific configuration I need to be aware of? Can I just clone the existing Sharepoint server on the VM and give it a new IP address, and then have it sit on the server in Asia? Thanks!

Comment: You probably can't as the SharePoint SIDs and Keys would all be the same which might cause problems.  I'd probably just do a fresh install.  That'll probably be faster than trying to transfer a VM image between the US and Asia.

Comment: Thanks, what happens if I already have a full backup of the Sharepoint production server setup, and I do a restoration to a Sharepoint test server? Will it be a duplicate with the SIDs and Keys? Will it point to the same SQL server?

Comment: Yep, if you have a backup it'll have all the same keys and sids, and will be pointing to the production SQL Server.